# Only move the marker and not the entire map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm trying to make a function that only moves the marker on a map, but the entire map loads when a new position is given. I'm using [Geolocator](https://github.com/onury/geolocator) to fetch the current position and watch it (I have changed `getCurrentPosition()` in `geolocator.min.js` to `watchPosition()`).

```
var map;
var map_coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(60.327821, 13.603855);
var map_options;
var marker;
var place;
var settings_timeout = 10000;

var geolocator_options = { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: settings_timeout, maximumAge: 100 };



$(document).ready(function() {

    geolocator.locate(geolocator_success, geolocator_error, null, geolocator_options, 'gm');



    function geolocator_success(location) {

        place = { 'latitude': location.coords.latitude.toFixed(6), 'longitude': location.coords.longitude.toFixed(6) };
        maps_coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(place['latitude'], place['longitude']);

        marker_solid(map_coordinates);
        marker_move(map_coordinates);

    }


    function geolocator_error(message) {
        alert(message);
    }


});



function marker_solid(coordinates) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coordinates,
        map: map,
        draggable: false
    });

    map.panTo(coordinates);
}

function marker_move(coordinates) {
    marker.setPosition(coordinates);
    map.panTo(coordinates);
}


function google_maps() {
    map_options = {
        center: map_coordinates,
        zoom: 14,
        minZoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 19,
        streetViewControl: false
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gm'), map_options);
}
```

[Demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/x6CX3/).

How can I accomplish to only move the marker on the map, and not load the entire map after each new position?

Comment: Remove the `map.panTo` lines surely, if you don't want to move the map?  Also you create a variable `maps_coordinates` but you then never use it, and use the previously-created `map_coordinates` instead

Comment: `maps_coordinates` was a typo. Sorry. I did what you said but the entire map reloads anyway. I have updated the demo at jsFiddle.

Comment: You are using `geolocator.js` library and it seems that it positions map to location found. I didn't check everything: there is function `finalize()` which draws map with new coordinates. Maybe there is an option to prevent that.

Comment: Using `toFixed` turns a number into a string.  However the google.maps.LatLng() constructor expects two numbers.  Remove that and/or add in a `parseFloat()` around it too

Comment: Many thanks, Anto! Geolocator's `drawMap()` was overlapping my own map! I deleted it from the function and now it working as I want it! duncan: Thanks :) I have added `parseFloat()` around `location.coords.l [...] .toFixed(6)`

Comment: Mmmh... why does your example show my own location? Come at my desk if you need help! lol

Comment: MrUpsidown: Because that function will use the devices GPS signal to locate you :)

Comment: OMG I didn't even see that hahah! Stupid me! I thought, oh that guy must be in my building! :-) I need holidays!

Comment: Haha! Yeah! You **really** need a lot of holidays ;)